# TypeScript Angular - Unknown provider by static $inject ['customServiceName']

Tags: angularjs, typescript

In this [the repo](https://github.com/Sergey80/angular_typescript_samples/blob/master/js/core/UserDetailController.ts)

In the controller, I'm trying to inject the `UserService`:

```
 class UserDetailController implements IUserDetailScope {

        static $inject = ['app.core.services.UserService'];              // static injection

        constructor(userService: app.core.services.IUserService) {
```

But it fails on the browser' console with:

> Unknown provider: app.core.services.UserServiceProvider <-
>   app.core.services.UserService <- UserDetailController

Could you say why?

Comment: Angular doesn't seem to know about your `UserService` provider

Comment: Yeah. Usually it happens when I forget to include service file in index.html for plain js/angular. But in this case, playing with typescript, I gave up.

Comment: Does your `UserService` have a dependency on the `UserDetailController ` controller? It shouldn't

Comment: @floribon no, you read those dependency chains as *"is a dependency of"*, ie `UserServiceProvider` is a dependency of `UserService` is a dependency of `UserDetailsController`

Answer (score 1):

Try upper casing the "U" in UserService in the constructor.  When angular goes to inject, it just does a match on the name of the service, and it matches case.

**EDIT**

Just realized you're using $inject, I'm leaving the first response up in case some others find it.

You didn't show us the code that registers the service, but that's the next culprit, usually.  I'd guess you're registering it as 'UserService', not 'app.core.services.UserService', or else you're doing an App.controller() instead of App.service() registration.  Those are the other two major culprits that come to mind.

Comment: Your edit answer is correct : https://github.com/Sergey80/angular_typescript_samples/blob/master/js/services/user.service.ts#L44

Comment: This   'angular
           .module('app.core.services')
           .service('app.core.services.UserService', UserService)'; does not work either

Answer (score 0):

you are writing the whole namespace to inject a service but there is neat way in which i do

```
    module portal {
      var app =angular.module('fooModule',[]);
          app.service(services);
          app.controller(controllers);

    }

    module portal.services {

       //all your services will go under this namespace
      export class fooService{
              //service body here
           }
    }


     module portal.controller{

      export class UserDetailController implements IUserDetailScope {

          static $inject = ['UserService'];                                 

         constructor(userService: potal.services.IUserService) {

      }
     }
```